# Heroku error running play framework 2

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0

I don't know why my Heroku application is in crashed state.

Log and code at https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan/blob/master/log.txt

Running application at http://libretitan.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your database is in an inconsistant state, so Play wants to run DOWNS evolutions, but you have not started your server with `-DapplyEvolutions.default=true` and `-DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true`. If this is a production system, I would not recommend doing that until reading about and fully understanding how [Play's evolutions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Evolutions) work because DOWNS could cause destructive changes to your data. The documentation can be found here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Evolutions

Since you are running on Heroku, be sure to also set `evolutions.use.locks=true` so the evolutions will still work if you scale to more than one dyno.

Comment: you are in right anyway dont work, i start the server with web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver                            Shold i upload the evolution file also? how generate it?

Comment: From the [`SQLSTATE:42601`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE) in your logs, it sounds like there is a syntax error in your evolution. Take a look at your at the `last_problem` in your `play_evolutions` table to get more details. Use `heroku pg:psql` to access the DB directly and then run `SELECT id, last_problem FROM play_evolutions;`.